# how to run virtualbox and android studio emulator together

Tags: android-studio, virtual-machine, virtualbox

So, I want to run VirtualBox and keep my settings isolated for that program but, if I will run android studio's emulator then I have to enable HyperV?

virtualbox requires my machine to have HyperV OFF,

android studio emulator requires it to be ON.

is there any way I can run both programs at the same time without going through this process along with reboot.